# select min(start_time) ,max(end_time) group by date

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have one table look like this

```
start_time                end_time 
2016-10-26 08:45:00       2016-10-27 09:45:00
2016-10-26 09:45:00       2016-10-26 10:45:00
2016-10-27 07:45:00       2016-10-27 11:45:00
```

I want my result to look like

```
start_time                end_time 
2016-10-26 08:45:00       2016-10-26 10:45:00
2016-10-27 07:45:00       2016-10-27 11:45:00
```

help me please

EDIT

```
I tried using 
Select min(start_time) start_time, max(finish_time) finish_time from times Group by CAST(start_time AS DATE)
```

but it keep showing wrong result when the start time and end time didn't happen on same day .

Comment: Please add what you have tried and where you have failed, SO is not a place where users give you ready code. Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, I think you should make the problem more interesting, by including a priod that starts between 9.45 and 10.45, and ending at 11.00, say.

Comment: Please read this first: [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And also... when grouped by date, isn't the max time on the 26th 23:59:59 !?!? Maybe you made an error in your data set.

Comment: edited .please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    MIN(startDate.start_time) AS start_time,
    MAX(endDate.end_time) AS end_time
FROM
    dates AS startDate
LEFT JOIN dates AS endDate
        ON DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(endDate.end_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Because start_time and end_time don't always happen on the same day you have to join the end_times and then look for latest time on the day.

This one might use an `index` on `end_time`. You should try to look for it if there is an `index` on the column.

```
SELECT
    MIN(startDate.start_time) AS start_time,
    MAX(endDate.end_time) AS end_time
FROM
    dates AS startDate
LEFT JOIN dates AS endDate
        ON endDate.end_time BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

**Example** [Fiddle with the steps](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b64246/3)

I am going to change your sample data a little, so you can see why I chose to use a `join` get the `end_time`. We are going to concentrate on the date **2016-10-26**.

The result will be the same as in your example:

```
start_time                end_time 
2016-10-26 08:45:00       2016-10-26 10:45:00
```

We have the following data. As you can see the values from the result are in different rows in the original data. The value of `start_time` in the first row, the value of `end_time` in the second.

```
start_time                end_time 
2016-10-26 08:45:00       2016-10-27 09:45:00
2016-10-27 09:45:00       2016-10-26 10:45:00
2016-10-27 07:45:00       2016-10-27 11:45:00
2016-10-26 10:30:00       2016-10-26 10:40:00
```

**First step** - preparing the data

The first step is, to get the matching end_time to the start_times. So for our dataset the end_times with date 2016-10-26.

To do this, we `join` by formatting the datetime column so it removes the time. We turn "2016-10-26 10:40:00" into "2016-10-26".

```
SELECT
    startDate.start_time AS start_time,
    endDate.end_time AS end_time
FROM
    dates AS startDate
LEFT JOIN dates AS endDate
        ON DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(endDate.end_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This gives us some rows with the same date on the start_time and end_time column. It is the cartesian product of start_time and end_time, limited to the same day.

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_time          | end_time            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-10-26 08:45:00 | 2016-10-26 10:45:00 |
| 2016-10-26 08:45:00 | 2016-10-26 10:40:00 |
| 2016-10-27 09:45:00 | 2016-10-27 09:45:00 |
| 2016-10-27 09:45:00 | 2016-10-27 11:45:00 |
| 2016-10-27 07:45:00 | 2016-10-27 09:45:00 |
| 2016-10-27 07:45:00 | 2016-10-27 11:45:00 |
| 2016-10-26 10:30:00 | 2016-10-26 10:45:00 |
| 2016-10-26 10:30:00 | 2016-10-26 10:40:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Second step** - grouping by day

Now we can simply group it, again we only want use the date of the datetime field, so we format it so the time gets removed.

```
SELECT
    startDate.start_time AS start_time,
    endDate.end_time AS end_time
FROM
    dates AS startDate
LEFT JOIN dates AS endDate
        ON DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(endDate.end_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This will give us some random resultset *, it is grouped by the day though.

- It might even look like the correct result, if the data is in the right order... dangerous. You can see it in the fiddle, the data for 2016-10-26 is in an order to display the 'correct' result, the data for 2016-10-27 is not.
- This query might as well give you an error because you are selecting non aggregated and non grouped columns - depends on your mysql version and configuration

**Last step** - taking the correct data

To get the correct result, we now use the aggregation functions `MIN()` and `MAX()`.

```
SELECT
    MIN(startDate.start_time) AS start_time,
    MAX(endDate.end_time) AS end_time
FROM
    dates AS startDate
LEFT JOIN dates AS endDate
        ON DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(endDate.end_time, '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(startDate.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d')

+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_time          | end_time            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2016-10-26 08:45:00 | 2016-10-26 10:45:00 |
| 2016-10-27 07:45:00 | 2016-10-27 11:45:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a fiddle? ;-)

Comment: sry i dont get what u mean :( can you explain in detail or have some kind of fiddle ?

Comment: @scarletwitch so, any feedback?